# Laravel Foreach in Foreach loop for display

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I learn actually PHP/Laravel and i'm blocked :

I have two tables :

- niveaux
- niveau_lang

I want to display all niveau_lang foreach niveaux.

When im out of my foreach, `$allLangs` is empty.

If someone can help me.

My Controller :

```
public function getAllNiveaux() {
    $allNiveaux = Niveau::all();

    foreach ($allNiveaux as $niveau) {
        $allLang = Niveau::getAllLangByNiveau($niveau->id_niveau);
        $allLangs = array();
        foreach ($allLang as $lang) {
            $allLangs[] = $lang->name;
        }
        $allLang = $allLangs;
    }

    $userName = Auth::user()->name;
    $userId = Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier();
    $userArgent = Planque::getArgent($userId);
    $userNiveau = Niveau::getNiveau($userId);

    return view('niveaux', compact(
        'allNiveaux', 'userName', 'userId', 'userArgent', 'userNiveau', 'allLang'
    ));
}
```

My blade file :

```xml
@extends('layouts.app')
    
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            @include('layouts.left')
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Niveaux') }}</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @foreach($allNiveaux as $niveau)
                            <div class="card-header">{{ $niveau->name }}</div>
                            @foreach($allLang as $lang)
                                <div class="card">{{ $lang->name }}</div>
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Why not just do `$allLang = Niveau::getAllLangByNiveau($niveau->id_niveau)->pluck('name')`? That 2nd `foreach()` seems completely unnecessary if all you're trying to do is map the `name` column. In your view it wouldn't be `{{ $lang->name }}` anymore, but rather just `{{ $lang }}`

Comment: Also, if you define `$allLang` inside the `foreach()` loop, you can't expect to be able to use it outside. PHP technically lets you do this by having loose loop scoping, but it's bad practice, and only the last iteration is available outside the loop. Have you considering using a Relationship? Then you could do `@foreach($niveau->langs as $lang) ...`

Comment: Sorry but i'm not sur to understand.
I have to write :

`$allNiveaux = Niveau::all();

    foreach ($allNiveaux as $niveau) {
        $allLang = Niveau::getAllLangByNiveau($niveau->id_niveau)->pluck('name');
    }
`

And :

`@foreach($allNiveaux as $niveau)
                            <div class="card-header">{{ $niveau->name }}</div>
                            @foreach($allLang as $lang)
                                <div class="card">{{ $lang}}</div>
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
`

Comment: I can't state that any more simply than I already have... You'll need to read up on some basic PHP, how to define variables and use them within or outside loops, etc, and consider reading the Documentation in Laravel for Relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships. This code is lacking that basic understanding, and that's not something I can teach you in the comments here.

Comment: keep `$allLangs = array();` outside the loop to stop initialization with each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for help, I understood my mistake